# CRM 2013 Execution Order when a Post Operation Create follows a Pre Operation Update Plugin

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a plugin which is fired on the Pre Operation Update of the Incident entity. The filtered attribute is new_SecureIncident.

As part of the plugin execution, I create a new record in another entity called Secure Access (this entity has a Look up to Incident entity).

Also, as part of this Pre Operate, I update a particular field new_DocumentSetURL on Incident entity.

This is how I set it.

```
Incident incidentBeforeUpdate = (context.PreEntityImages != null && context.PreEntityImages.Contains(this.PreImageAlias)) ? context.PreEntityImages[this.PreImageAlias].ToEntity<Incident>() : null;
Incident incident = (context.InputParameters != null && context.InputParameters.Contains(Target) && context.InputParameters[Target] is Entity) ? ((Entity)context.InputParameters[Target]).ToEntity<Incident>() : null;
```

I later update the value of new_DocumentSetURL as below

```
incident.new_DocumentSetURL = incidentDocumentURL;
```

Now, I also have a Post Operation Create Plugin on the Secure Access entity.

**Problem:**

The Plugin on Secure Access still has the old value of the new_DocumentSetURL. How can I organize my plugins so that the create plugin on Secure Access entity picks up the correct DocumentSetURL value?

**Full Process Description**

The Pre Update on Incident calls a Web Service to SharePoint. This WCF web service call takes as input paramters the DocumentSetURL value and returns a modified one. I update Incident with the modified DocumentSetURL.

Then, I create a new Secure Access record. This again makes a call to the WCF web service and it takes two parameters, the DocumentSetURL (of the lookup on Secure Access) and the name (primary attribute) of Secure Access.

Please note that the Secure Access records can also be created manually. So, I am just calling the `service.Create(new_secureaccess)` and not writing the functionality of PostCreate of Secure Access within the PreUpdate of Incident.

That way, I would have to write only once the PostCreate of Secure Access and it would be called irrespective of whether it is manually created or automatically created (by the PreUpdate of Incident plugin).

Comment: @Filburt: I am not setting anything in the (PostCreate) Plugin of Secure Access. I am just retrieving the value of DocumentSetURL of the Incident entity (which is a lookup field of SecureAccess). 

The Secure Access entity does not have the field DocumentSetURL in it. It merely has a lookup to Incident which in turn has the DocumentSetURL field.

Comment: @Filburt: Ok, this is what happens. The Pre Update on Incident calls a Web Service to SharePoint. This WCF web service call takes as input paramters the DocumentSetURL value and returns a modified one. I update Incident with the modified DocumentSetURL. Then, I create a new Secure Access record. This again makes a call to the WCF web service and it takes two parameters, the DocumentSetURL (of the lookup on Secure Access) and the name (primary attribute) of Secure Access.

contd.

Comment: @Filburt: Please note that the Secure Access records can also be created manually. So, I am just calling the `service.Create(new_secureaccess)` and not writing the functionality of PostCreate of Secure Access within the PreUpdate of Incident. That way, I would have to write only once the PostCreate of Secure Access and it would be called irrespective of whether it is manually created or automatically created (by the PreUpdate of Incident plugin). Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the whole process - I adopted your comments to the question to improve readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the problem may be the order of operation.

You are creating the Secure Access record in the PreOp stage of the Incident, so the value you set for `incident.new_DocumentSetURL` has not yet been submitted to the database; hence your attempts to retrieve this attribute from the linked Incident of your newly created Secure Access record only "knows" about the old record.

Instead, move the logic which creates the Secure Access record to the PostOp of the incident. This will be *after* your changes to `incident.new_DocumentSetURL` have been saved to the database.

If you wanted, you could move the entire logic you have in the PreOp of Incident to the PostOp (so all logic will be in one spot), but this would require you to make a call to `service.Update(incident)` after setting the value due to the processing stage. If you go this route though, make sure you update the Incident *before* creating your Secure Access record (so the order of operation doesn't come into play).

Comment: Thanks. I did exactly that, about couple of weeks ago, but forgot to update SO. Thanks for clear explanation of the problem. I couldn't have done a better job!